# Can I measure large force using series FSR?

Tags: sensor, resistors, measurement, load-cell

Is it possible to measure large force using multiple Force Sensitive Resistors in a series? Will I have to stack the resistors up? Will the measurement be reliable if I place them side by side?

I want to measure the pressure applied by a standing human on a surface. I do not expect the entire weight of a human on the sensor, but whatever part of the foot that touches the FSR. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a force sensitive resistor, use a [load cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_cell). This is a 4-wire device with a resistor bridge; the resistance between pairs of wires changes slightly when weight is applied. They're available in a wide range of weight ratings, from those suitable for weighing out individual SMD components, right up to those used to weigh trucks.

You'll need an instrumentation amplifier to get useful measurements out of it; a common choice is the [INA125](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina125.pdf).

Comment: I am also concerned about the form factor. Load cells that I came across were all large. I want to have a few under the insole of a shoe.

Comment: @LordLoh. There are specialist loadcells. FSRs aren't really designed for precision or high weight applications.